# i can pass a number but not a variable into a javascript objects method

Tags: javascript

Im creating a simple graphing application when i try to pass the value of a text input box into a function (e.g.1) the routine fails but when i pass a number (e.g.2) it works fine can anyone explain this to me.

e.g.1 // fails

```
var x = document.getElementById('xInc').value;
var y = document.getElementById('yInc').value;
grid.drawGrid(x, y);
```

e.g.2 // works

```
var x = 30;
var y = 40;
grid.drawGrid(x, y);
```

Comment: x and y will be strings ... you may want to parseInt or parseFloat or any other number of ways to convert a string to a Number

Comment: You can't use a string where a number is expected. As noted above, you'll need to parse (interpret) the string as a number

Comment: thank you for your replies i actually figured it out by myself you are of course right in your replies. 

var x = document.getElementById('xInc').value;
var y = document.getElementById('yInc').value; 
var numx = Number(x); 
var numy = Number(y);

grid.drawGrid(numx,numy);

Comment: @AlanJohnson I wouldn't use the Number constructor for this. Javascript has parseInt and parseFloat global functions for this purpose.